# Validate method getting NullPointerException during login in Struts2

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2

I am doing programmatic validation, when I click the submit button, the validate method has been called, but it shows `NullPointerException`. It won't validate, but I am unable to find my mistake.

[image: Screenshot]

---

index.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>

<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="insert">
    <s:textfield name="" key="user.name" />
    <s:textfield name="" key="user.pass" />
    <s:submit value="login" />
</s:form>
```

---

UserLogin.java:

```
package jack;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class UserLogin extends ActionSupport {

private String username;
private String password;

//getter and setter method

@Override
public void validate() {
    System.out.println("validate");
    if (this.username.equals("") || username.length() == 0) {
        this.addFieldError(username, getText("user.wrong"));
    }
    if (this.password.equals("") || password.length() == 0) {
        this.addFieldError(password, getText("pass.wrong"));
    }
}

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("execute");
    return SUCCESS;
}
}
```

---

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="a" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="insert" class="jack.UserLogin">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

---

struts.properties:

```
 struts.custom.i18n.resources=Mybundle
```

---

Mybundle.properties:

```
user.name=username
user.pass=password
user.wrong=enter username
pass.wrong=enter password
```

Comment: @downvoter what i am asking wrong here,i faced some issue,during login time,so i posted my query here,as per my knowledge i don't ask anything wrong here,kindly tell me reason for  putting downvoting..

Comment: Did you create getter and setter method for username and password variable? If not please create getter and setter methods and check once.

Comment: Don't post stacktarce as an image, edit the question and replace it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame work is unable set values for your variables, your jsp should be as below

```
<s:textfield name="username" key="user.name" />
<s:textfield name="password" key="user.pass" />
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have a null pointer exception on line 29 of UserLogin.java. Assuming that this is the line:

```
if (this.username.equals("") || username.length() == 0) {
```

It means that `username` is null. You can't call a method (in this case `equals`) of a variable (in this case `username`) that is null. You will get exactly the error as described. What's happening is that struts is not properly assigning values to these variables. You need to fix that first.

Answer (score 0):

Before validation check for null in validate method. See below.

```
if(this.username!=null && this.password != null)
```